# Javascript in HTML forms, Accumulating Total Realtime

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of a problem with my HTML and JAVASCRIPT Combination.

I'm trying to create a page where I am able to add values by a certain parameter. It's it in this picture of how it would work.

[image: PIC1]

The whole page:

[image: PIC2]

Here's my code to this overall HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Naawan Receipt System</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/header-second-bar.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

<header class="header-two-bars">

  <div class="header-first-bar">
    <div class="header-limiter">
      <h1><a href="/home">Municipality<span>Receipt</span></a></h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="/form" class="selected">FORM</a>
                <a href="/logs">LOGS</a>
                <a href="/query">QUERY</a>
                <a href="/user">USER</a>
            </nav>
            <a href="/logout" class="logout-button">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header-second-bar">
    <div class="header-limiter">
            <h2>User: {{ user }}</h2>

            <nav>
                <a href="/addparameters"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Nature of Collection</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Results</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Participants</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Settings</a>
            </nav>
    </div>
 </div>
</header>

<!-- CONTENT HERE. -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/indextest.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/indextest.css">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-sm">
    <div class="container" id = "contact">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="h1">
                Accountable Form 51 <small>Made easier</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block; ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                            O.R Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter O.R Number" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                            Payor</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "payor" id="payor" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required="required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">
                            Nature of Payment</label>

                                <div id="RadioGroup">
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod"  checked="checked" value="CASH"> Cash<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="CHECK"> Check<br>

                                <div id="PaymentsCHECK" class="desc" style="display: none;">
                                <br>
                            Drawee Bank<input type="text" name="dbank">
                            Number<input type="text" name="dNum">
                            Date<input type="text" name="dDate">
                                </div>

                                <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="MONEY"> Money Order<br>

                                <div id="PaymentsMONEY" class="desc" style="display: none;">
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" name="dbank">Money Order No.
                                </div> 
                                </div>
                        </div> <!-- FORM GROUP END -->


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                            Memo</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="25" required="required"
                            placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    </div><!-- FIRST COL6 END -->
              </div><br><br><br><br><!-- ROW END -->

              <div class="col-md-5" style="display: inline-block; ">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2>Type in Nature of Collection...</h2>
                    <form>  

                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="form" list="languages" placeholder="Search" type="text" required>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="amount" list="languages" placeholder="Amount" type="number" required>
                      <br>
                      <button onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add Item</button>
                    </form>

              <datalist id="languages">

                {% for row in rows %}               
                  <option value = "{{row[0]}}">
                {% endfor %}

              </datalist>
               </div> <!-- JUMBO END -->

                <h6> <label>Date:<span></span>
                </label>   {{date}}</h6>
                <h3><fieldset disabled>
                <label>Total </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "total" id="total"><br></p>
                </fieldset></h3>
                </div><!-- COL5 END -->

<!-- </div> --><!-- REMAIN OR NOT? DEPENDS ON DEBUG PROCESS LATER -->

<div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Nature of Collection</h2>
      </div>
      <div>

<!-- ACCUMULATION TABLE STARTS -->
        <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>

                      </tr>
                      <tbody>



                      </tbody>




        </table>
<!-- </form> --> <!-- CHECK LATER -->


<datalist id="languages">
            {% for row in rows %}
            <option value={{row[0]}}></option>
            {% endfor %}
</datalist>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                    Submit Form</button>
                          <br>
                    </div>
          </div>

          </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*EDIT HERE LATER*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='paymentmethod']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Payments" + test).show();
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function deleteRow(o){
     var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
         p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
      }
     function addRow()
      {
        var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
          newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
          cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
          cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
          cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
          name = document.getElementById("form").value,
          amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


          delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
        cell1.innerHTML = name;
        cell2.innerHTML = amount;
        cell3.innerHTML = delete1;
      }

</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am done in that part, this time I wanted to add the values of each amount added and display it real-time on the Total inputbox. So I put  an id to the cell which the amounts will be generate in the javascript:

Before:

```
 function addRow()
  {
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
      newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
      cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
      cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
      cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
      name = document.getElementById("form").value,
      amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


      delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = amount;
    cell3.innerHTML = delete1;
  }
```

After:

```
 function addRow()
  {
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
      newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
      cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
      cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
      cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
      name = document.getElementById("form").value,
      amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


      delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = amount;
cell2.id = "qty
    cell3.innerHTML = delete1;
  }
```

"qty" here will match the ID's of all entry on cell 2 and will add it and will display it on the id total.

But when I do this the value box at the top side pops out an error:

[image: PIC3]

It prompts me to enter a value on the unrelated boxes.

I also tried separating them by forms but it didn't work.

I tried this on the other forms I have and its working, I was just using a checkbox plus textbox, however on this page I am unable to do it. What should I do on this case?

A checklist just to be clear:

1. I generated ID's for each cell added
2. I used that ID to evaluate on a javascript script
3. The accumulated total was supposed to go to the ID "total" but it didn't happen.
4. I already tried separating the forms, but this time it only reloaded and the entries weren't added.
5. I have a separate button for saving all fields named "Submit Form"

Any input or ways how to do this in your opinion?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is due to nested forms, which are not a constructed supported by browsers. Make sure you close your first form before starting the new one - then validation won't cross-contaminate.

To be clear, this has nothing to do with the way you're totalling your values (though that has some issues to be resolved on its own, e.g. you're accessing the `value` of your elements, while you've never set it - instead you want to be getting their `innerHtml`).